# No Authentication after Probe Response modified for security

Tags: security, wifi

I am working on 802.11i security implementation and I am stuck quite at the beginning. My work is based on existing framework which broadcasts open WiFi network and devices are successfully able to connect.

In order to inform STAs of access restrictions, I added RSN (Robust Security Network) element into Tagged parameters of Beacons and Probe Response frames. I defined both suites (Group and Pairwise) with 802.11 standardized values setting to AES and AuthKey setting to both PSK and 802.1X.

After this frame is sent, no Authentication Request is generated from STAs and I got response on all of them (Win7, Android and iOS) that device cannot connect. I compared Wireshark traces with multiple connection establishments, and cannot figure out what doesn't add up. Only thing I modified is addition of RSN and this RSN is absolutely the same as in other production connection attempts.

What I thought is that either device rejects frame because of improper implementation/format, or it doesn't support offered security mechanisms. But then - removing RSN field (making network open) allows STAs to proceed with Authentication Req; and looking into Probe Responses from real APs, they have the exact same structure and contents of RSN.

And other interesting behavior is that Apple device (iPad) doesn't even recognize network as secured with RSN field implemented while both Win7 and Android do.

Any ideas what am I missing or misunderstanding?

Screenshots: First is working real communication, second is my implemented modification.

[image: Reference PROD WPA2 secured WiFi network created on Huawei device]

[image: Implemented Probe Response frame with RSN field added]

Comment: They are not the same. Notice how the working one sets RSN capabilities to `0x000c` while yours is set to `0x0000`. You also don't seem to have the protected bit set in the capabilities information fixed parameter.

Comment: The capabilities informed of just possibilities behind the scope of Probes. However, the protective bit was the key. I did not set it on purpose, because I was referring to 802.11i standard: "Bit is set to 1 only within data frames and within management frames of subtype Authentication. Field is set to 0 in all other frames."
Thank you very much for your input.